# Vue router - cannot lazy load component - Unexpected Token

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to [lazy load](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) the Login component for my login route. When building webpack I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected Token
```

The Login.vue component works fine if I import and assign it the same way I do the Home route.

I'm baffled because I believe this code should work based on [this blog](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/).

The line that fails below is:

```
component: () => import('../components/Login.vue'),
```

### router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../components/Home.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)


export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
            meta: {
                permission: "anonymous",
            },
        },

        {
            path: '/login/',
            name: 'login',
            component: () => import('../components/Login.vue'),
            meta: {
                permission: "anonymous",
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "uiv": "^0.11.4",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.7",
    "vue-acl": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-js-cookie": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
}
```

### Screenshot of compilation error

[image: Screenshot of error during compilation]

Comment: what version of webpack are you using?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. I had to attend to crying baby. The double edged sword of working from home :-)

Comment: I've expanded my original question with package.json details. Webpack version 2.7.0

Comment: @pymarco Can you add more details about this `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token`? At this time we don't know if it is or not actually came from your router.js file!

Comment: @IvanVilanculo, I have added a screenshot to the OP.

Comment: @pymarco try to change from `component: () => import('../components/Login.vue')` to `component: () => System.import('../components/Login.vue')`

Comment: Yes!! That did it! Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept? Thank you Ivan!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your webpack is not configured the spec! Só there are two ways to solve your problem!

The first one is to change all occurence of `import('path/to/component.vue')` to `System.import('path/to/component.vue')`

And the second is using BABEL with the folowing configuration

> .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-export-extensions"
  ]
}
```

Resources

[ES6 Modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#es6-modules)

[Dynamic Import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/)

[Stage-2 Babel Preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/)

Comment: Thank you. Both approaches worked. I have created a .babelrc file, except I removed the "plugins" part. Cheers

Comment: That works, but how do you group components when it is System.import('./components/Component.vue')?

Comment: @Tadas could you explain a bit more about your question?

Comment: Thanks to this answer I removed babel and fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution can be used with these versions of dependencies:

```
"laravel-mix": "^2.1.11", 
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",

component: (resolve) => { require(['../components/' + nameComponent + '.vue'], resolve); }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [vue-webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) to start your project and use [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/) to lint it? if you are, simply update your `package.json` to include:

```
"standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ignore": [
        "build"
    ]
}
```

This will ignore any error warning `Unexpected token import` on your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Add `parser` and `parserOptions` in *.eslintrc.js* file worked for me. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833471/9485417) helped me